# Convert JsonArray to JsonObject Jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to convert JsonArray to JSON Object, from this:

```
[{
  "departmentID":"baccf1ba-d9ca-4480-46cd-08d7e5f27472",
  "criteria":"absensi",
  "weight":21,
  "status":true
}]
```

to this:

```
{
  "departmentID":"baccf1ba-d9ca-4480-46cd-08d7e5f27472",
  "criteria":"absensi",
  "weight":21,
  "status":true
}
```

Comment: Do you mean from c# to jquery or the opposite or within c#?

Comment: @Jabberwocky good question.  The *assumption* is from the title "jquery" and the code provided is javascript that it's a javascript question and has erroneously been tagged [c#] [html] [jquery] (should be just [javascript]).  Normally I'd just change it myself, but as you've raised the question, better to have OP clarify (if they come back).

Comment: @s13 FYI "JSON" is "JavaScript Object Notification" - a *string*.  It's always a string.  What you have here is a `javascript array` and a `javascript object` - there's no such thing as a "JSON Object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const truc = 
      [ { departmentID: "baccf1ba-d9ca-4480-46cd-08d7e5f27472"
        , criteria: "absensi"
        , weight: 21
        , status: true
      } ] 

const bidule = {...truc[0]}


console.log(bidule)
```

Comment: Why not just `const bidule = truc[0]` - am I missing something?

Comment: yes you are missing to create a new object,  you just create  a pointer on truc[0] object